# Calculating the Hausdorff Dimension of specific profinite groups

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, profinite-groups

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the Hausdorff dimension of some profinite groups and came across the following paper ([here](https://pure.royalholloway.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/6351231/Hausdorff.pdf)) which defines the Hausdorff dimension for a closed subgroup $H \leq G$ as
$$dim(H)=\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log{ \vert H:H \cap G_n \vert }}{\log{\vert G:G_n \vert}}$$
where $ \{G_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a filtration of the profinite group $G$.

The given example says that:

> Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_p \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ (where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of p-adic integers) and $H=\{0\} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}_p$. Then if the Hausdorff dimension is computed relative to the filtration $G_n=p^n \mathbb{Z}_p \bigoplus p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$, we obtain $\dim(H)=\frac{1}{2}$.

We have defined the p-adic integers as the set of infinite sums $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i p^i$ for $0 \leq a_i \leq p-1$.

However, I am confused about how to calculate $\vert H:H \cap G_n \vert$ (and $\vert G:G_n \vert$.

I think that:

$G$ is the set of ordered pairs $(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i p^i, \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i p^i)$ for $0 \leq a_i,b_i \leq p-1$.

$H$ is the set of ordered pairs $(0, \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i p^i)$ for $0 \leq b_i \leq p-1$.

$G_n$ is the set of ordered pairs $(\sum_{i=n}^\infty a_i p^i, \sum_{i=n}^\infty b_i p^i)$ for $0 \leq a_i,b_i \leq p-1$.

$H \cap G_n$ is the group of ordered pairs $(0, \sum_{i=n}^\infty c_i p^i)$ for $0 \leq b_i <p-1$

And $H: H \cap G_n = \{ h(H \cap G_n):h \in H \}$

But I can't see where I go from here?